# How should I bundle Java with my Windows application?

Tags: java, windows, installation

I have a Windows application based on Java, that I should like to install with Java bundled. The installation framework is NSIS. The application executable should be guaranteed to invoke the bundled Java, so there's no clash with other Javas installed in the system.

What's the best way to achieve my goal? I haven't tried to solve this kind of problem before, and have little experience with Java, so I don't know which solutions are out there. I think I'd prefer Java to be embedded in the application's executable, if feasible, otherwise I guess Java could be installed along with it (with the executable pointing to said Java).

**Edit:**
This project already generates an executable (.exe), via NSIS. The executable will by default use the system Java, but apparently it'll prefer a JRE in the same directory (i.e. bundled) if present.

**Edit 2**:
The scenario that made me want to bundle Java with this application was that I received an executable for it built with 32-bit Java, which failed (silently) on my system which has 64-bit Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure you don't want to use the computer JRE? In most cases it's preferable.
You can see [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Simple_installer_with_JRE_check) (and the included link) some examples with installers that check JRE number and install it (globally) if necessary.

If you really prefer to include your own JRE in the installer and always use it - what prevents you from doing it? It's just a matter of your main program point having some way of konwing the JRE location and forcing to use it. That depends on how you pack/invoke your Java program. Normally, it would be feasible, perhaps with a simple .bat file - perhaps to be created at installation time.

Comment: If using the computer's JRE, I'd need to make sure it's compatible. In my case, I discovered that my system Java which is 64-bit, was unable to launch an executable built on another developer's machine (probably with 32-bit Java). I have no idea how to ensure that the system Java is compatible, and if not I'd have to bundle Java anyway.

Comment: Using the computer JRE is best.  I hate applications that include their own copies of Java, cygwin, etc.  They never patch these on time, so they suffer from security holes long after the fix is released, and they take up disk space which with SSDs remains a big concern.

Comment: @Ben Voigt They never patch these "on time"? Usually they never patch those at all in my experience :/ And then you spend your time figuring out how to get them to use the default JRE - or just get rid of the problematic app at all. Especially with Java you have to work really hard to get compatibility problems between different JRE versions..

Comment: @Voo: Usually the next version of the application comes with whatever Java version got released in the meantime.  But that means your Java patches are waiting for an application update.  I find that most of these apps can be fixed with `rd /s jre` then `mklink /j jre C:\Program Files\Java\jre6`, but it would be nice if the app developer did it right to begin with.

Comment: @aknuds1 Then I'd think the first approach would be to find out why the program is silently failing on 32bit java. That really shouldn't happen and could indicate some lingering bugs that could bite you later on (check your native code to make sure it's portable?)

Comment: @Ben Voigt Yeah I assume setting a symlink on Windows should help there - actually really good idea. On Linux that'd probably one of my first ideas, no idea why I haven't thought of using symlinks under Windows (well it's an quite abstract feature there that's probably the reason)

Comment: @Voo I don't know how easy it'd eventually be to make the app work under 64-bit Java (it fails under 64-bit Java, not 32-bit), as I haven't been involved in writing it. I think I've seen apps in the past that won't work under 64-bit Java (Hudson?), so I kind of figured it was a more or less common problem in the Java world.

Answer (score 0):

The solution we used(A few years ago, but still I think the best way).

Find a program which can generate an exe file from a jar file(Google is your friend, I can't remember the name). Note that this .exe file will still need a jre. It is just a smart way to make an exe which contain your .jar file, and which start the java process automatic. (This also allows you to set a custom icon on your .exe file).

The java sdk which you use to develop/compile your java application, also contains a folder called jre, which contain a copy of the jre.

Include this folder with the installer, so the jre folder is located in the same folder as the .exe file. Then the .exe file will use the included jre, and the jre will not be installed on the computer, so you prevent any problems.

Comment: make sure you're allowed to do that though. I'm not certain all JREs are free to redistribute.

Comment: Which exactly is why you need the jre included in the java sdk. (I assume, we talk standard java 1.6 for windows.

Comment: there still are some legal/licencing requirements, even just for the JRE part of the JDK. e.g. IBM's JRE terms contains stuff like: "(2) Your application must redistribute other Redistributables identified in this license with the JRE Redistributables unless Your application is designed to run only on general computer devices (e.g., desktops and servers) and not pervasive devices; ", and other legal matters about indemnification and restrictions on re-redistribution. "Just copy the stuff" is bad advice.

Comment: True, but we are talking about using the oracle jre to run his own application on desktop windows XP/Vista/Windows 7, which is explicit allowed.

Comment: @Mat It's standard Java 1.6, that should be free to redistribute, no?

Comment: It's allowed with restrictions. The Oracle JRE licence also has restrictions on what type of computer you're installing to, indemnification legalese, restrictions about not altering anything in it...

Comment: And in case anyone cares: The license is at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u21-license-159167.txt - see "B.  License  to   Distribute" But to sum up: You may distribute if you need it to run your own program. And you can't change anything in the jre. And you can't include components which have the purpose of replacing anything in the jre.

Comment: Actually, in this project we already generate a .exe, through an NSIS script AFAIK (I just joined this project, so I don't know that much yet). I just tried your suggestion of including the JDK's JRE with the .exe, and it appears to work. What is the actual mechanism at work here?

Answer (score 0):

Well one extremely simple solution that works actually quite nice if you don't have to get an executable, is just using a simple Windows Batch file that starts the jar and having a shortcut to it so you get your preferred icon on it. For the average user there's no real difference - after all the default is to suppress known extensions on Windows (horrible default but well) - and for people who do know what an exe is, the solution should be quite apparent anyways.

That way you can also easily start the included java or better yet offer both versions and just change a variable in an ini file, which really is much nicer - nobody wants or needs X different JRE versions that are outdated and are nothing more than security problems. Still can't harm to offer a version that includes the JRE for people without a java install to make it as simple as possible for them.

One example for this behavior would be [weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)..

Comment: I've discovered (from another answer) that the application .exe can automatically use a JRE bundled alongside it, if present, which means I guess that one doesn't need to write a wrapper batch script.

Comment: Well then you need an exe that starts the java application - which obviously will work just fine (a handful lines of c code to get the jvm to start the correct jar file), but I don't see any advantages in that over a simpler script.

Comment: The project already generates an exe is my point :) So that should rule out the need for a wrapper script.

Answer (score 0):

[launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) seems to offer to bundle an embedded JRE.